# An "extension" operator or relation for objects of a category or types?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

In a Cartesian closed category we can "extend" basic objects A, B to their product $A \times B$. Similarly, we can relate co-product and exponential objects to their parts. Is there an operation or formal notation to describe extension of the type:

$\mathbb{R}$ extends $\mathbb{N}$

or

$\lambda x.x^2: \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ extends $\lambda x.x^2: \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Have you considered using *monomorphisms*?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean exactly by "extends" but you may be interested in the notion of a subtype: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping